# align height in <div> style inline-block

Tags: html, alignment, height, css

I had this http://jsfiddle.net/g5bE8/ . 
I need to align height in all rows, how can I do that?

```
<div class="test">
   <div class="row">one block</div>
   <div class="row">
      three block
      <br>three block
      <br>three block
      <br>three block
      <br>three block
   </div>
   <div class="row">three block</div>
   <div class="row">one block</div>
   <div class="row">three block</div>
   <div class="row">three block</div>
   <div class="row">one block</div>
   <div class="row">
      three block
      <br>dewdfwe
      <br>rgegregrethree block
      <br>dewdfwe
      <br>rgegregre
   </div>
   <div class="row">three block</div>
</div>

.test{margin: 20px;}
.row{display: inline-block; margin: 2px; text-align: center; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius:5px;  vertical-align: middle; color: black;}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: code in question and code in fiddle have nothing in common..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g5bE8/287/

Comment: http://joxi.ru/mvDfU_3JTJD4B0P9tng http://joxi.ru/v_DfU_3JTJAYCG05-v4 
I needs align height of div's , in every row.

Comment: I shouldn't use min-height and height to the blocks, http://jsfiddle.net/g5bE8/288/

Comment: http://joxi.ru/GvTfU_3JTJDjB0X5UQ4

Comment: why don't you use table instead?

Comment: items are responsive in page.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Static height rows.

You can specify the height of each row, and then assign `height: 100%;` to the cells of that row. This isn't dynamic, though. If you want the *contents* to be vertically aligned to, you'll want to put another div inside of the cell which does NOT have a predefined height, and use `vertical-align: middle` once again.

This method requires you to separate each horizontal group into different markup, eg:

```
div.row
   div.cell
   div.cell
   div.cell
div.row
   div.cell
   div.cell
   div.cell
```

Alternatives:

If you cannot separate rows, you will likely need javascript to calculate the height for you. The same thing applies as above, each cell will be 100% height of the row. You do not (necessarily) need to split each row, though, but the height may need recalculated.

This is very open-ended, though. There are a hundred ways to do this with javascript.

Here is one solution: http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

It sets the height of all cells on the same row to the height of the tallest cell. It does not vertically align anything, but as I said, just put another div inside that has `vertical-align: middle`. Or look into one of the many other vertical alignment options. Again, a hundred ways to do this.

Comment: I updated my answer with what I could, although the scope of the question has changed. Try to provide more information with the initial question next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Result code I make via js. 
there are some pictures of result.

http://joxi.ru/4cfgU_3JTJDiB2K7aoE
http://joxi.ru/_cfgU4wyTJDjAixFFRI

var line1 = [];
                     var line2 = [];

```
                 var tumbler = 0;
                 var height = $('#t_1').offset().top;

                 $("div.product__bl").each(function() {

                     if (tumbler == 0) {
                         if (height < $(this).offset().top) { tumbler = 1; line2.push(this.id); } else { line1.push(this.id);}
                     } else { line2.push(this.id); }
                     //alert(this.id);

                 });

                 var maxHeight = 0;

                 $.each(line1, function(){
                     var item = $('#'+this).height();
                     if (item > maxHeight)
                         maxHeight = item;
                 });
                 $.each(line1, function(){
                     $('#'+this).height(maxHeight+10)
                 });


                 maxHeight = 0;

                 $.each(line2, function(){
                     var item = $('#'+this).height();
                     if (item > maxHeight)
                         maxHeight = item;
                 });
                 $.each(line2, function(){
                     $('#'+this).height(maxHeight+10)
                 });
```